# how can update value in python using PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql

```
def deopsit_amount(self,value, cash):

    rows=cur.fetchall()
    update = """Update customer set amount=%s where id=%s"""
    for row in rows:
        if row[0]==value:
            row[4] +=cash
            cur.execute(update,(amount,id))
            conn.commit()
```

1st it show an error unexpected indent

2nd i want to update amount when user deposit amount

Comment: rows[0] is id and row[4] is amount

Comment: what library did you use to manage PostgreSQL?

Comment: import psycopg2

Comment: can you show me the error that you found?

Comment: def deopsit_amount(value, cash):
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent

Comment: The indentation error probably means something has got mixed up with the spaces, maybe you've accidentally got a tab in there, or one space too many or few?

Comment: at the end of fun conn.commit() it show statement expected, found py:DEDENT